# Find the gradient of $\frac{x}{x-y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

It seems simple on the face of it, but I cannot figure out how to actually do this. I know that you have to find the partial with respect to $x$ and also with respect to $y$, but that's where I get lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left.\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{x}{x-y}\right) = \frac{(x-y)-x}{(x-y)^2} &=&\frac{-y}{(x-y)^2}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{x}{x-y}\right) &=& \frac{x}{(x-y)^2}\end{array}\right\} \Longrightarrow \nabla \left(\frac{x}{x-y}\right) = \frac{1}{(x-y)^2}\begin{pmatrix}- y \\ x\end{pmatrix}$$

Both times, you should use the derivation rule:
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right) = \frac{f'(z)g(z)-g'(z)f(z)}{g^2(z)},$$
one time with $f(z) = z, g(z) = z-y$ and the other time with $f(z) = 1, g(z) = x-z$

Comment: So basically you just use the quotient rule the same as you normally would, but treat any other variables as constants. Okay, I suppose that should've been intuitive but it wasn't. I've never done partials with fractions that had both variables in them before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is exactly that :), when you proceed partial derivatives with respect to a given variable, you should consider all the other variables as constants.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y)=x/(x-y)$

Just use the definition

$\bigtriangledown f(x,y)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-y/(x-y)^2$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x/(x-y)^2$

so

$\bigtriangledown f(x,y)=(-y/(x-y)^2,x/(x-y)^2)$